# RadioInfo.getCurrentNetworkName() giving a null value?

Tags: blackberry, operators

I am using RadioInfo.getCurrentNetworkName() to get the operator name in the blackberry device. It is working fine since now when I noticed that for a given device, this function is returning a null value. The code used is the following:

```
String operator = "";
try { operator = RadioInfo.getCurrentNetworkName(); } catch (Exception ex) { }
Dialog.alert(operator);
```

The alert gives a null value. So i guess an exception is thrown when getting the network name. What can be the reason behind this?!

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Have you tried printing out the Exception and getting the message from it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the API documentation getCurrentNetworkName() returns:
**The name of the carrier network, or null if the device is not registered on any network**

Is the device in question provisioned on a cellular network?

Comment: Yea the device is registered on the network. And in the home screen of the blackberry you can clearly see the carrier name. So that's a problem

Comment: Well, you can put something in the catch clause to see if an exception is being thrown, but since operator == "" going into the try clause, and null coming out I think the call is working. You can try going in to advanced options to the Host Routing Table, select the menu and Register Now to make sure the device is actually registred on the network.