# How to get short message service center number?

Tags: blackberry

I need to know service center number to determine operator in my BlackBerry app. I've tried `RadioInfo.getCurrentNetworkName()` method to get operator name directly, but the result is not proper for my case.

Is it possible to know this information ? Is there any other ways to determine user's operator ?

Answer (score 2):

The methods `GPRSInfo.getHomeMCC()` and `GPRSInfo.getHomeMNC()` returns a numeric code for Country Code and Network Code for the Home network.

This will get the name ([refer to this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6981257/radioinfo-getcurrentnetworkname-giving-a-null-value)):

```
RadioInfo.getCurrentNetworkName();
```

**Edit :**

```
String mcc = Integer.toHexString(RadioInfo.getMCC(RadioInfo.getCurrentNetworkIndex()));
```

Comment: what if the device uses a wireless network for internet access ? In that case how can I determine the operator that the user is member of ?

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I need to know the operator information of the SIM CARD. According to these methods that you mention; if I move my device from South Africa to England, my app will show different MCC and MNC values. I want to get the exact description about, for example, my MTN line in my BlackBerry device.

Comment: GPRSInfo.getHomeMCC() results must be converted as mentioned on here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7090052/getting-the-mcc-and-mnc-for-the-operator-on-blackberry  Thanks